# MySQL Database Design issue for labor work Invoice

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, invoices

I am designing database for labor work invoice. 
In that I have following entities.

Labor_invoice_table(This is main table I have created)

- Date
- Invoice No. (PK)
- Name of labor
- Job Description
- Amount per Job
- Total Amount

Here I am confuse about Job Description and Amount per Job Invoice Line Item.On each Invoice I have multiple Jobs and for each Job its amount.

I search about it on google.
Here also I found one useful detail [link](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/invoices_and_payments/index.htm)
Found that I should create new Table

Labor_Job_Description

- Invoice No.(FK parent Labor_invoice_table)
- Job Description
- Job Amount

So that multiple job can be stored in another Table.

Is it proper way? Or should I try something else?

Comment: Is the job description & amount fixed, meaning same description & amount can be part of multiple invoice?

Comment: No, this job description & amount are only part of this invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [relation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-relationship-tools.html) for this.

May be you need many to many relation. Because each labor can have many job or each job can have many labor.

labor

- id. (PK)
- name_of_labor
- Date

job

- id(PK)
- job_description
- Job_amount

labor_job

- labor_id.(FK parent invoice_table)
- job_id.(FK parent labor_table)

Now you are ready for join query.

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
  labor_job AS lg
JOIN
   labor AS l ON lg.labor_id = l.id
JOIN
   job AS j ON lg.job = j.id
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate a invoice you can use a query like

select  ID,LabourName,InvoiceDate,Description,Amount
From Invoice 
Inner join Invoice.ID = Labor_Job_Description.InvoiceID
For total amount:

Select sum(amount) 
   from Labor_Job_Description where Labor_Job_Description.InvoiceId=
Insert will be something like this..

Insert into Invoice (InvoiceDate,LaborName) 
  values (curdate(),'name');

set @invoiceID=  LAST_INSERT_ID();

Insert into Labor_Job_Description (InvoiceNo,Description,Amount)
  values (@invoiceID,'desc', 10);